# Pointing the first element of the list of the objects

Tags: c++

I have a task like

1. Create a class of a Student, with properties such as: name, address,
   telephone. age, sex, year of studying, …, and methods to read and
   write these properties as private data.
2. Create a class of students
       list (one directional) with the pointer to the first element of the
       list of the Student objects.

For the first step, i wrote a code like this in the student.cpp.

```
#include "student.h"

class Student
{
private:
    QString name;
    QString adress;
    int telephone;
    int age;
    int year_of_study;
public:
    Student();
    Student(QString name, QString adress,int telephone,int age,int year_of_study);
    QString getName();
    QString getAdress();
    int getTelephone();
    int getAge();
    int getYos();
};
```

For the second step, i dont know how to point the first element of the list of the Student objects. Will i produce a list in the student class and in the studentlist class will i point the first element?

Comment: That's one poorly formulated assignment. You are also missing setters.

Comment: @dtech how can i correct setters? I'm new in the c++ programming and qt, sorry if it is so basic.

Comment: Well, for every property you will need a `setProperty()` function as well. Although if they will all be readable and writable, you might as well have the members public and be done with it, no good reason for all the redundant boilerplate code. Also, maybe your assignment implies `Q_PROPERTY` when it says property?

Comment: @overflish, you are saying this a .CPP file and included the .h in it `#include "student.h"` ... actually this is your class definition the .h file

Comment: @MohammadKanan so does it have to be in .h file?

Comment: @overflush, it seems that, like me, you are new to c++. are you using Qt creator .. how did you generate this code? what do you mean by _"list of the Student objects"_

Comment: @MohammadKanan I'm taking a class and we're using this program. i'm not in the very beginning but i'm unexperienced. I dont really know thats how it is written in the task. I didnt understand either.

Comment: @overflush, are you using Qt Creator or not? how you are compiling your code?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Yes i'm using Qt creator

Comment: Ok, then, in Creator create new project   .. once you have a project in Creator you can add Student class to your project

Comment: @MohammadKanan I've already added the class. What i want to do is the second step.

Comment: @overflush, well this comments section is not to guide you through your assignment .. you need to design your class using a good c++ reference, only if get an issue along the way, someone can help you .